# How to track Google Adsense Click in iOS / Swift Programatically

Tags: ios, swift, admob, adsense

Is there any way to track the google ad is clicked in iOS/Swift Programatically. I didn't find any solution for tracking the number of taps clicked on any google Ad using Google Ad Sense.

Comment: There is an app that does this called "AdSense". Or do you mean you want to do it programmatically?

Comment: Programatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/admob/ios/banner#ad_lifecycle_event_callbacks) - there are delegate functions. I think you can achieve it like this:

I suggest you to make class scope variable `clickCount = 0` and inside the delegate function add one to it.

```
/// Tells the delegate that a full screen view will be presented in response
/// to the user clicking on an ad.
func adViewWillPresentScreen(_ bannerView: GADBannerView) {
  clickCount += 1
  print(clickCount)
}
```